# What does "A type can name itself as the concrete type when closing a type argument" mean?

Tags: c#, generics, programming-languages, computer-science

From C# in a Nutshell

> A type can name itself as the concrete type when closing a type
>   argument
>
> ```
> public interface IEquatable<T> { bool Equals (T obj); }
> public class Balloon : IEquatable<Balloon>
> {
>   public string Color { get; set; }
>   public int CC { get; set; }
>   public bool Equals (Balloon b)
>   {
>     if (b == null) return false;
>     return b.Color == Color && b.CC == CC;
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> The following are also legal:
>
> ```
> class Foo<T> where T : IComparable<T> { ... }
> class Bar<T> where T : Bar<T> { ... }
> ```

What does "A type can name itself as the concrete type when closing a type argument" mean?
Could you show where it is in the examples?

What do "concrete type" and "closing a type argument" mean?

In the examples, there are no instantiations of the generic types, so where are the "type arguments" and "concrete type"?

Thanks.

Comment: I imagine it's referring the this?:  `IEquatable<Balloon>`

Answer (score 2):

The class `Balloon` is a concrete type. You can use it in order to create instances of `Balloon` type objects as below:

```
var balloon = new Balloon 
{ 
    CC = 1;
    Color = "Blue" 
};
```

On the other hand `IEquatable<T>` is a generic interface. Whenever a type implements this interface, the `T` is replaced by this type.

So If you want your custom type called `Balloon` to implement this interface, you just have to declare first that this class implements it as below:

```
public class Balloon : IEquatable<Balloon>
```

and inside the body of the class you have to implement the method `Equals`.

Note now that since the signature of this method is the following:

```
bool Equals (T obj);
```

You have to change to this:

```
bool Equals(Balloon obj)
```

since now `Balloon` is your concrete type.

Comment: Thanks.  How shall I understand the last two examples. `class Foo<T> where T : IComparable<T> { ... }` and `class Bar<T> where T : Bar<T> { ... }` ?

Comment: You are welcome ! I am glad that I helped. Regarding the first one, You can create a class of type `Foo<T>` provided that the type `T` that you will use implement the `IComparable<T>` interface. For instance, you could use the class `Temperature` that is defined here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd(v=vs.110).aspx and implements the `IComparable<Temperature>`. That means you could create a class of type foo as `var fooTemperature = new Foo<Temperature>();`.

Comment: Regarding the second case, the constructed type T that can be used should inherit from `Bar<T>`. Let for instance that we have class `public class Example : Bar<Example> { }`. Then you can use this class a specific type for the constructed type `T` as below: `var bar = new Bar<Example>();`